# Should I wait for RTCPeerConnection.setRemoteDescription() & RTCPeerConnection.addIceCandidate() Promises to settle?

Tags: webrtc, rtcpeerconnection, peer-connection

1. [RTCPeerConnection.setRemoteDescription()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/setRemoteDescription) returns a Promise that resolves once the value of the connection's remoteDescription is successfully changed. Do I need to wait for this Promise to resolve successfully before calling
   [RTCPeerConnection.addIceCandidate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/addIceCandidate)?
2. Furthermore `RTCPeerConnection.addIceCandidate()` returns a Promise which is fulfilled when the candidate has been successfully added to the remote peer's description by the ICE agent. Should I wait for this Promise to resolve successfully before adding the next available candidate via `RTCPeerConnection.addIceCandidate()` or can IceCandidates be added in parallel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not necessary, see the description of the operations chain [in the specification](https://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#rtcpeerconnection-interface) which ensures in-order execution.